# Kак поменяется размер изображения по свёрточной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Архитектура сверточной сети:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shap  e=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Как поменяется размер изображения?
Гуглила - не понимаю параметр Conv2D(32,(3,3)) как соотносится с (28,28,1)?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен. После свертки (`Conv2D`) - это уже будет не изображение, а набор признаков после применения 32х фильтров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в 2 раза уменьшится.
Подробно https://habr.com/ru/post/454986/

```
model.summary()
**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**
    Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 28, 28, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                62730     
=================================================================
Total params: 63,050
Trainable params: 63,050
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________
```

Comment: Обожжите. Уменьшится в 2 раза изображение в 32 фильтрах только **после пулинга 2x2**, что совершенно логично. Но вопрос же был не об этом. У вас же output shape 28, 28, 32 т.е. 32 фильтра размером 28x28 на выходе слоя `conv2d` - ну, и что там уменьшилось?

Comment: За уменьшение отвечает только слой pooling - об этом и речь, и в сводном представлении модели видно, что было 28,28, а стало после max_pooling2d :14,14. Так что все правильно - берем архитектуру, а размеры смотрим в model.summary()

Comment: Значит, я неправильно понял ваш вопрос, я думал он про слой `Conv2D`. А в нём размер изображения никак не меняется, просто на выходе получается 32 изображения того же самого размера после обработки свёрточными фильтрами. А то, что дальше в слоях нейросети размер обрабатываемых данных как-то меняется - это уже вопрос не про размер картинки, практически. На выходе из нейросети вообще 10 нейронов, например.

Comment: Спасибо за комменты, но я скопировала экзаменационный вопрос и тоже долго думала, что вообще имеется  в виду.

Answer (score 1):

А не пробовали читать [документацию](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)? :)

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters,
    kernel_size,
```

- filters: Integer, the dimensionality of the output space (i.e. the number of output filters in the convolution).
- kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of 2 integers, specifying the height and width of the 2D convolution window. Can be a single integer to specify the same value for all spatial dimensions.

Т.е. в вашем случае в этом слое будет 32 фильтра с размером ядра свёртки 3x3. В общем-то это никак не соотносится с размером входных данных, да и не должно соотноситься.

Отдельно вот про [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) ссылка, но вам точно надо почитать что-нибудь про `2D convolution`.

Comment: Может padding='same' позволяет не менять изображение? Этот вопрос из экзменационных...Тогда есть ли пример СНС архитекутры, меняющей размер изображения?

Comment: "подбираясь к концу нейронной сети мы уменьшим размер изображения до вектора оценок по классам, расположенного вдоль глубины (3-го измерения)" (https://habr.com/ru/post/456186/)

Comment: @svil, если я правильно помню, при `padding="same"` две первые размерности тензора  сохраняются

Comment: @svil padding отвечает за то, как свёрточная матрица применяется на краях изображения https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-padding-in-convolution-layer/